# Create an array from Cursor

Tags: java, arrays, cursor

Of the following two methods (both of which overwrite `long[] mArray`), which would be preferred?

The first method iterates over the `Cursor`, calling `ArrayList.add()` for each row, then iterates over the `ArrayList` to copy the values to the array.

The second method iterates over the `Cursor` twice. Once, calling `size++` each time to count the rows, and again to copy the values to the array.

```
public void arrayFromCursor1(Cursor cursor) {

    // create a temp ArrayList to add to as we don't
    // know how many rows are in the cursor
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    // iterate over the cursor
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            list.add(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name")));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        // create a long[] of appropriate length and copy values from the
        // ArrayList using a for loop
        final int size = list.size();
        mArray = new long[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mArray[i] = list.get(i);
        }
    }
}

public void arrayFromCursor2(Cursor cursor) {

    // no need for a temp ArrayList this time
    // iterate over the cursor simply counting the rows
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int size = 0;
        do {
            size++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        // create a long[] of appropriate length and iterate over the
        // cursor again, this time with a for loop copying values to the array
        mArray = new long[size];
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            mArray[i] = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the `toArray` method of your list. `mArray = list.toArray(new long[list.size()])`.

Comment: I take it back, just realised this doesn't work for arrays of primitive types...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with what I think is a clean, simple solution for creating an array from a Cursor. This is useful when storing arrays in foreign-key tables, and will work with primitives.

```
public long[] arrayFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {

    int length = cursor.getCount();
    long[] array = new long[length];

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name"));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```